# Does JavaScript focus() triggers scroll horizontal bar of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus, scrollbar

**Scenario:**

I have a web page with multiple web controls and on that page I have `horizontal` `scroll bar`.

**Case:**

Now, consider a case where, on click on a `button(event)` I set focus on a particular control and while click on button that control is not visible on page, it is towards end of web page and `button` is at the top of page.

```
$("#ControlId").focus();
```

**Question:**

Now, my question is does setting focus on that control will also `trigger` the horizontal scroll bar and show the control on page?

Comment: I was tempted to answer a simple "Yes", but in fact this question is so simple that would take yourself about 5 minutes and 6 lines of code to find out :)

Comment: After asking I have tested this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $("#ControlId").focus();
});
   $( window ).scroll(function() {
  $("#ControlId").val("Yes!" );
   });
```

```css
button{
margin-bottom:2000px;
}
input{
margin-left:2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Does JavaScript focus() scroll horizontal bar of browser?</button>
<br>
<input id="ControlId" value=""/>
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, I got the answer and it is "YES" :) I have also tested same.